# Cannot open port 8080

Tags: linux, port, iptables

I'm running a VmWare with an application under JBoss starting up on port 8080.
I'm able to access the app from outside the VM if the iptables are off.

However, I must turn on iptables due to some rules, but I couldn't open port 8080.
I tried: `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` and `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` but no success.

Output of `netstat -tulpn` with iptables rule:

`Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6617/java`

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have probably APPENDED the rule to the table after a policy that denies access.  You should try INSERTING the rule.  The difference is replacing -A INPUT with -I INPUT, so the command would be

```
-I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Another possibility (not sure where you have specified the rule) is that you need to modify the FORWARD chain rather then the input chain - if this rule exists on the VM host rather then the VM.

Comment: It's not working yet, when I execute `service iptables save` it's going to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. This is what I got now: `[root@devsrvr ~]# more /etc/sysconfig/iptables
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [23:1780]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23:1780]
-A PREROUTING -d 172.17.38.10 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.38.129
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [151:22125]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [275:33909]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT`

Comment: I've just found out that the rule `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 172.17.38.10 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination
 192.168.38.129` is doing that. Any idea of how can I have that rule and also access through port 8080?

Comment: As your default policies all appear to be "ACCEPT", I can't see any reason why this is not working.  I'm guessing you have dropped the rest of the firewall and it works now ?  If so, what does it look like with the Firewal on ?  If the firewall is meant to be like this, what does the firewall on the VM show ?

Comment: You write "You have probably APPENDED the rule to the table after a policy that denies access. You should try INSERTING the rule" <---From the little I know of iptables, if a policy denies access, then appending a rule should work.It doesn't matter if the accept rule is first or last..The only time appending a rule might not work is if there is a deny rule before it.But I don't think there should be.. AFAIK(not much) i'd guess the only normal/useful configurations are blacklists and whitelists   so with a policy of deny, the rules should be only accept. And appending or inserting won't matter

Comment: There may be a rule missing allowing established connections through, so maybe also "iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" may be needed to match the returning traffic.     @barlop - Rule order is important when using IPTABLES, if traffic matches a drop rule before its matched, it will be dropped at that point.  Rules are processed in order they are added, with -I adding them at the beginning  and -A adding them at the end.

Comment: @davidgo  Re ur comment,I know that order can make a difference, and your -I idea and ESTABLISHED,RELATED idea is good(though a mystery what isn't going through).But the line you wrote in your post was as if appending a rule to a table after a policy that denies access, was a problem.When perhaps u meant appending a rule to a table after a rule that denies. (then regardless of policy,it won't work ./ will be denied).  Bear in mind that as you know.. rules are followed then the policy. BTW you may mean `-I INPUT 1`  since -I is insertion(and anywhere), rather than prepending. You missed the 1`.